# term references field not loading terms in node edit form

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

In latest D7, I have a field which holds term references. In a cck content item, I can see the label of the field, but not the term options - they're just not loading (neither in checkbox, select or autocomplete widget).
Whereas in other parts of the site (eg dependency settings), the widget loads well with the available options. 
I've disabled the form column module, changed to a different theme, as I thought might have something to do with this, nothing. no luck. I'm lost.

Comment: Have you selected the correct Vocabulary in field settings? Have any term exists in selected Vocabulary?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct vocabulary - looking at the devel query log, the query works well and gives the correct result. Now I wonder why these results don't find their way into the select field.

Comment: Can I see the screenshot of field setting.

Comment: Screenshot of the settings: http://snag.gy/pHfte.jpg

Comment: Are you checking the field value using user 1?

Comment: yes, and as well with other users I have on the system, too.

Comment: It seems some other issue. It may be conflicts with other module. Have you added any other module like entity_references?

Comment: There's a good row of modules, though after this issue was reported, I disabled all the modules I had activated before, though didn't help. and yes, entity reference module is used. Interesting thing is, that this happens only to some term reference fields, but not to all.

Comment: Well try to disable entity reference also.

Comment: disabled that one, too. - no changes. Next step would be to find out how the values are loaded into the field coming from the database, just to break down the failing function.

Comment: well, then use entity reference instead term eference.

Comment: found the bug, though don't know how it got in there. 
Within the field settings (screenshot above), the 'event type' was selected, though in the field_config data column, the vocabulary ID was missing. In the end, it's working, though some things I'm still wondering about - from where the field settings got its information, when in the field_config no vocabulary id was set? 
So eventually, I've inserted the vocabulary id manually into the data column, and bam, it worked. Jeez!